# How do I display a dynamically resized image in Kohana without saving it?

Tags: kohana

I have an image path string stored in  a database

It goes like: img/uploads/imagename.jpg

I have a controller:

```
$this->image = new Image($wines->image)

//this is assuming that I have a wines table with the image property

$this->image->resize(60, 250, Image::AUTO)

echo $this->image->render();

//the problem is nothing is rendered

//Is there a better way of doing this? the image path that I am passing at the Image object //instantiation is the result of a query
```

Comment: Note that an image processing (resize image) in request time requires more processing from the server than echoing a simple string within an image tag. If you have thousands of visitors, your server may begin to slow down and take a lot of processing. Advice: Always do image resizing in the back-end, when the image is uploaded by the administrator of the website content.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use "echo"
2. Move the render to a view

Answer (score 0):

You need not use the echo itself. render() itself echoes the output to the browser. Maybe, you need to use render(true), as per the document.
http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/image#render

EDIT: Also be careful with the paths. If possible, use absolute paths OR preferably paths relative to your document root.